# Composition of attractors

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Given two 2D attractors, for example two Clifford Attractors, is it possible to combine them in an attractor in 4D? For example something of the form:
$x_{n+1} = \sin(a y_n) + c \cos(a x_n)$,
$y_{n+1} = \sin(b x_n) + d \cos(b y_n)$,
$w_{n+1} = \sin(a z_n) + c \cos(a w_n)$,
$z_{n+1} = \sin(b w_n) + d \cos(b z_n)$
is a 4D attractor?

From the definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Mathematical_definition) I am not sure such an equation would satisfy the third condition.

Alternatively, could you recommend attractors in 4D (or more) with explicit equations?

Comment: What is "the third condition?" You linked a paragraph with no explicit list of conditions. That being said, this should still be a strange attractor as nearby trajectories are still exponentially separating

Comment: Edited to link the correct paragraph